# Write Text on Image without increment of Size?

Tags: android, optimization, android-canvas, bitmapimage, image-compression

I am writing some text on Image which will be compressed.

Image sie `2048 x 1536` Something px

I first tried to write first 
    It throws OutOfMemory Exception

then i first compressed it to `1024 x 768`

Then Written text on the Image

It increased the Image KB's from `100KB` to `640KB`

While writing text i can `compromise` the `Image quality but not the text Quality`

on Compression quality set to  `30`  the text also goes `downsample`

**Questions:**

1. is there any process to `write then compress` or `Compress then Write`
   text without changing the ImageSize(in KB)?
2. I want Image Size(in KB) as less as Possible?
3. And also When  inSampleSize  is set to 3 it does not work and only the image of 2048 , 1024 , 512 using 1 , 2 , 4 is created as output I want image of some size arround 700px maintaining aspect ration.

**Codes:**.

**Method for StampingImage**

```
public void stampMyImage(String filePath, String text, Bitmap bitmap) {
        String[] str = text.split("\n");
        filePath = "/sdcard/geoTag/1imagelong_001_001_0002_0002_1135_130708144229.jpg";
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Bitmap dest = null;
            try {
                dest = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e1) {
                Log.e("Exception", e1.getMessage());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Error e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
            Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Verdana", Typeface.BOLD);
            Paint tPaint = new Paint();
            tPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            tPaint.setTextSize(40);
            tPaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
            tPaint.setTypeface(tf);
            tPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            tPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            cs.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
            float textHeight = tPaint.measureText("yY");
            int index = 0;
            for (String Oneline : str) {
                cs.drawText(Oneline, 20f, (index + 1) * textHeight + 25f,
                        tPaint);
                index++;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                        "/sdcard/timeStampedImage.jpg");
                dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Method for Regular Compression**

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    int quality = 70;
    myBitmapClose = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUriClose.getPath(),options);
    if (myBitmapClose != null) {
        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(imgUriClose.getPath());
        try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        myBitmapClose.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);
        if (bos != null) {
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        }
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Image Sample 
[image: The Sample Image with Text Written on it]

**See Also**

Some useful links i followed

[How to write text on an image in Java (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318205/how-to-write-text-on-an-image-in-java-android)

[Generate a image with custom text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124896/generate-a-image-with-custom-text-in-android)

[Drawing Text (TimeStamp) Over image captured from Standalone Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436201/drawing-text-timestamp-over-image-captured-from-standalone-camera)

Comment: Do you really need to save the text as part of the image ? I would save the description of the image as text and bytes from the image in one file. Then each time you want to display you read both and text can be displayed to any screen

Comment: What can i do bro all the info is all ready in database but my boss want it so what can i do 
yes i want to do exactly what i have written 
i am already displaying using image in div's background on web sent through mobile

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the allowed allocation memory for your app.
When you load images to bitmap variables (decodeFile or bitmap.copy) try to set the options to   decrease image quality. For example, when you do bitmap.copy try to set the options like this:

```
bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);
```

Comment: The same error i have tried already so i went with bitmap.getConfig()

Comment: The Main Problem is i am to compress it and first to write and compress there are too many things all are writing in same way maybe some method to do in a linear behaviour